# JavaFx window to AWT window

Tags: java, macos, javafx-8

I wrote a programm and I want to disable fullscreen on Mac, but standard apple library doesn't work. Because it needs an AWT window instead of my javafx one :

```
if(System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().indexOf("mac") >= 0){
        com.apple.eawt.FullScreenUtilities.setWindowCanFullScreen(stage.getScene().getWindow(), false);
}
```

Can you explain how can I convert javafx window to awt window. If not can you recommend me another apple library for setWindowCanFullScreen, but with javafx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

convert is a bad idea.

try something like this:

```
if(MAC) stage.setFullScreen(false);
stage.fullScreenProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>(){
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> ov, Boolean oldv, Boolean newv){
            Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    if(MAC && oldv==false && newv==true)stage.setFullScreen(false);
                }
            });
        }
});
```

edit: A solution without a "small delay" stay unknown and interesting for us!

Comment: Yep, I've tried this, but it doesn't work. It's just work once and then my application just doesn't want to work : I can't click on buttons, I can't even close  it by the default close button

Comment: Sorry, I'm not at home right now, but I think it will solve my issue. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, it actually works just fine. But with small delay.